# Using Onclick event of button inside of component

Tags: delphi, custom-component

I create a component and add a Tbutton to it.
 now I want to create OnClick event for my Component that execute when user click my component's Button at run time
How can I do that?

Comment: This is a very broad question. Please narrow it down if you want a good answer. Also, this website works best if you show other users what you have tried so far...

Comment: "I create a component and add a Tbutton to it." That is extremely vague. Please provide details, including sufficient code for us to understand. This is going to mean that you need to spend more time working on your question. My rule of thumb here is that the more time you spend writing a good question, the better the response and the more you will learn.

Comment: See [OnClick event handler for control in custom component not working](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23046743/576719).

Comment: We need code; [edit] your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@LU_RD's answer is probably what you are looking for.

I wrote a smaller example that should be similar to what you are doing.

```
interface

TMyComponent = class(TCustomControl)
private
  embeddedButton: TButton;
  fOnButtonClick: TNotifyEvent;
  procedure EmbeddedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
protected
  procedure DoEmbeddedButtonClick; virtual;
public
  constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
published
  property OnButtonClick: TNotifyEvent read fOnButtonClick write fOnButtonClick;
end;

implementation

// Attach embedded button event handler onto embedded button
constructor TMyComponent.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  // .. other code
  embeddedButton.OnClick := EmbeddedButtonClick;
  // .. more code
end;

// EmbeddedButtonClick fires internal overridable event handler;
procedure TMyComponent.EmbeddedButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // If you want to preserve the Sender, extend this method
  // with a sender argument.
  DoEmbeddedButtonClick;
end;

procedure TMyComponent.DoEmbeddedButtonClick;
begin
  // Optionally if you need to do additional internal work
  // when the button is clicked, you can do it here.

  // Check if event handler has been assigned
  if Assigned(fOnButtonClick) then
  begin
    // Fire user-assigned event handler
    fOnButtonClick(Self);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Very Good thank you very much **Mr. Anderson** your code is very useful